# Find the components of a vector u which has initial point (-1,-2), terminal point (x,0)for some x∈ℝand which points in the same direction as (1,3)

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

How can I find the components of this vector u? 
I know how to find the components of a vector when all coordinates are given (taking the coordinates of the terminal points away from the initial), but how can I go about finding the x coordinate of the terminal point?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Find the components of $u$ in terms of $x$; set them equal to a multiple of $(1,3)$, and solve for the unknowns

Comment: Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 0):

$u=(x,0)-(-1,-2)=(x+1,2)$.  Set this to be a multiple of $(1,3):\quad  (x+1,2)=\alpha(1,3).$

Can you solve this for $x$?  The answer to the question is then $x+1$.